# Using a batch file, can I rename files within a ZIP file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which renames files.

Is it possible to rename files within a ZIP file? If not, is it possible to "extract" them in the background, rename them and "add" them back into the same ZIP archive?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you trying to rename them into .zip (which would obviously not work), or do you want to actually add them to a ZIP archive and (possibly) compress them?

Comment: I have a .zip file which contains documents. I want to rename these documents with my .bat-file. It works fine when unzipping them and then using the .bat. However, when I try to rename the documents WHEN THEY ARE STILL ZIPPED, it doesnt work(which makes sense). Is there a way to still make this happen?

Comment: Understood. Made an answer using a freeware (portable too) program that I am familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command-line version of [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

For example:

```
7z e archive.zip -o C:\Temporary\Dir
ren C:\Temporary\Dir\*.* *.renamed
7z a archive.zip C:\Temporary\Dir\* -aoa -y -sdel
```

`e` stands for Extract, `-o` is the output directory.
Then you `ren` the files inside (using whatever you have in your batch script as of now).
Finally, we `a`dd all (`*`) files from `C:\Temporary\Dir` back into the same `archive.zip`, but since they exist, we would like to overwrite all (`-aoa`) and make sure we agree (`-y`) to any prompts (in case they appear).
Oh, and because we like to make it clean, `-sdel` makes sure that all files that have been added to the archive are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Zip format store metadata and data separately for each entry.
So it would allow you to iterate over entries and change the entry name on the fly without decompressing/compressing data, in a streaming, memory and disk efficient way.

I don't know a tool proposing it out of box so you would have to use a library such as [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip/) and bind it with you favorite language.

So if your zip archives are small and you don't perform this task over and over, you should stick to a extract/rename/archive process.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little late, but since it worked for me I'll share my findings from:

http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#rename

Basically you have to use the zipnote utility.

```
Example:
     zipnote foo.zip > foo.tmp
     ed foo.tmp
     ... then you edit the comments, save, and exit ...
     zipnote -w foo.zip < foo.tmp

"@ name" can be followed by an "@=newname" line to change the name
```

It will still rewrite the whole file, but one step shorter than extract file, rename, delete file from zip, add renamed file back.

Comment: And hopefully does not lose all kinds of metadata which .zip archives store...

Comment: Can you explain more fully what you are saying about ``"@ name"`` and `"@=newname"`?

Comment: @grawity The example I posted is from the zipnote utility --help itself. Basically you dump the meta data from an existing zip file into a temporary file, edit that file and add a new line after the "@ name" line with "@=newname" (where name and newname are values you need to change). Then load the meta data back into the zipfile and hope everything updates.

Comment: @G-Man My zip file doesn't seem to have any meta data at all, and I dont know what meta data zips support beyond file/archive comments. But I'd expect them to get lost. From what I noticed this method is much faster than any extract/rename/repack or delete/readd with new name. But it requires some extra work in between, using it in scripts is probably not worth it.

Comment: (1) You seem to have cross-addressed your comments.  The one addressed to @grawity appears to be an answer to my question, and vice-versa. (2) Zip files normally contain the modification date/time of the zipped files; that’s an example of metadata. Others include original size, compressed size, compression method, compression ratio, encryption method, checksum, and attributes / permissions.  And it looks like WinZip might keep pathname as a separate metadata item from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract -> rename -> compress like suggested above, or you could edit the hex data of the zip in order to change the names inside of the file

An example:
[eg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRFc1.png)

Obviously this is much harder to do with batch, than it is to extract, rename, and compress, but if you must rename it while it's still in the zip it is possible, since the actual name of the file exists in the .zip, you can also convert the original name to hex, search for that hex array in the file and replace it with a new one.